# is_trivially_destructible: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Bar2’

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

For example I need some a wrapper class, one of it's jobs is to tell me if the container `is_trivially_destructible` or not:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(T *t) {
    std::cout << "a trivial" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>> {
 public:
  Foo(T *t) {
    std::cout << "not a trivial" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

and two test class:

```
class Bar1 {
};

class Bar2 {
 public:
  ~Bar2() {}
};
```

and it works fine:

```
int main() {
  Bar1 bar1;
  Bar2 bar2;
  Foo<Bar1> foo1(&bar1);
  Foo<Bar2> foo2(&bar2);
}
```

but if the test class got more complicated:

```
class Bar2 {
 public:
  Bar2() : foo(nullptr) {}
  Foo<Bar2> foo;
  ~Bar2() {}
};
```

I got an error:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Bar2’

I guess that until the end of declaration of class `Bar2`, the `Bar2` class is incomplete, so access `Bar2` in declaration of `Bar2` is forbiden.

So is this a wrong design pattern? If not, how can I fix this problem?

The whole program which can reproduce this issue:

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T, typename = void>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(T *t) {
    std::cout << "a trivial" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>> {
 public:
  Foo(T *t) {
    std::cout << "not a trivial" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Bar1 {
};

class Bar2 {
 public:
  Bar2() : foo(nullptr) {}
  Foo<Bar2> foo;
  ~Bar2() {}
};

int main() {
  Bar1 bar1;
  Bar2 bar2;
  Foo<Bar1> foo1(&bar1);
  Foo<Bar2> foo2(&bar2);
}
```

Comment: can you post a single program that gives the error message, currently you have 4 snippets and it's not exactly clear how they go together to create the problem

Comment: @M.M the full program is pasted.

Comment: *"I guess that until the end of declaration of class Bar2, the Bar2 class is incomplete"* Correct, So you cannot have member `Foo<Bar2> foo;`. pimpl idiom might help.

Answer (score 2):

In the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) it is explicitly written that for `std::is_trivially_destructible` the type must be complete:

> T shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array
>   of unknown bound. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If an instantiation of a template above depends, directly or
>   indirectly, on an incomplete type, and that instantiation could yield
>   a different result if that type were hypothetically completed, the
>   behavior is undefined.

And then also:

> Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message

So it seems ok that your program doesn't compile.

Note that this is ok, though:

```
class Bar2 {
 public:
  Bar2();
  ~Bar2();
  Foo<Bar2>* foo;
};

Bar2::Bar2(): foo(new Foo<Bar2>(nullptr)) {}
Bar2::~Bar2() { delete foo; }
```

Comment: Hi, my `Foo<T>` class is sort of a container like std::vector, make it a pointer either make it no sense nor the `delete` will got problems, that's drive me crazy.

Comment: Then maybe you should not use `enable_if`, but use `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value` directly inside your class methods; E.g. for constructor:
`  Foo(T *t) {    if (std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value)    {      std::cout << "a trivial" << std::endl;    }    else    {      std::cout << "not a trivial" << std::endl;    }  }`